# Pass a vector as a range to std::sort - C++17

Tags: c++

I wrote this code in order to simplify the use of **std::for_each** when I need to go through an entire collection:

```
namespace ranges {
    template<typename Range, typename Function>
    Function for_each(Range &range, Function f) {
        return std::for_each(std::begin(range), std::end(range), f);
    }
}
```

So that I can use it like this:

```
ranges::for_each(a, foo);
```

This had worked for me and since I also have to sort entire collections, I thought it would be a good idea to implement the same process with **std::sort**, just like this:

```
namespace ranges {
    template<typename Range, typename Function>
    Function for_each(Range &range, Function f) {
        return std::for_each(std::begin(range), std::end(range), f);
    }

    template<typename Range, typename Function>
    Function sort(Range &range, Function f) {
        return std::sort(std::begin(range), std::end(range), f);
    }
}
```

When I add that code to my namespace, the compiler throws me the following error message:

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do? I'm using the C++17 standard and *g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0* to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `for_each` works, because the definition of `std::for_each` you're using is defined as follows:

```cpp
namespace std {
    template <class Iterator, class Function>
    Function for_each(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Function f);
};
```

*However*, `std::sort` as invoked is defined as follows:

```cpp
namespace std {
    template <class Iterator, class Function>
    void sort(Iterator first, Iterator last, Function comp);
};
```

In your definition of `sort`, you cannot return the result of the call to `std::sort`, because the return types for the two functions are distinct.

Comment: I get it now, I'll find how to correct this then. Thank you!

Comment: @DiegoFC  Ehm, you forgot to accept the answer?